# Build complex Model.find request

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, waterline

I am building an API using Sails.js

At the moment I am executing raw sql requests to find a list of Status :

```
        Status.query("SELECT Status.* FROM Status,User where Status.user = User.id and User.isPrivate = false group by status.id  order by status.id desc limit "+limit+" offset "+offset, function(err, status) {
            if(err) return next(err);


            console.log(status)
            console.log(res)
            res.json(200,status);
        });
```

2 problems :

1- It is raw SQL so i will not be able to switch to Mango or anything else because my code is linked to my database choice
2- Model.find automatically load relationships (here Status.user and Status.find) and raw sql only load the ID

2- I am looking for the syntax to build 'complex' requests using Model.Find to let me get the exact same result than the raw sql one and also do things like

```
AND:
[
    {
    or:
        [ 
            {a=1,b=2},
            {a=2,b=1}
        ]
    },
    {c=6}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i successfully found how to do !

**So the goal was to convert this request :**

```
Status.query("SELECT Status.* FROM Status,User where Status.user = User.id and User.isPrivate = false group by status.id  order by status.id desc limit "+limit+" offset "+offset, function(err, status) {
            if(err) return next(err);


            console.log(status)
            console.log(res)
            res.json(200,status);
        });
```

**To a Model.find request using Sails.js syntax in state of mysql. Here you go :** (without pagination but its easy to find how to do)

```
Status.find({}).populate('user',{isPrivate:'false'}).exec(function(status,err){
                if(err) return next(err);


                console.log(status)
                console.log(res)
                res.json(200,status);
            });
```

Have fun!